# Admin element which is Update Timetable

Tags: python

```
#science_stream_timetable 
timetable = []
#Monday
timetable.append(["English","Maths","Biology","Moral"])
#Tuesday
timetable.append(["Add_Maths","Physics","Malay"])
#Wednesday
timetable.append(["History","Chemistry","English"]) 
#Thursday
timetable.append(["Moral","Biology","Maths","Malay"])
#Friday
timetable.append(["Physics","Chemistry","Add_Maths","History"])

day = input("Day of the week?").title()
 
#PROCESS
lessons=[]
if day=="Monday":
  lessons = timetable[0]
elif day=="Tuesday":
  lessons = timetable[1]
elif day=="Wednesday":
  lessons = timetable[2]
elif day=="Thursday":
  lessons = timetable[3]
elif day=="Friday":
  lessons = timetable[4]
else:
  print("Not a valid week day!")
  
#OUTPUT
print("Your lessons on this day:")
for lesson in lessons:
  print(lesson)
```

I want to update this timetable. For exp; I'm doing a school management system and view timetable is one of the element in user menu, now I want to add update timetable as an element in admin page.

Comment: Are you simply asking about assignment? Like `timetable[0][0] = "something else"`? I'm not sure i fully understand the question

Comment: Hi maybe there's a typo in my question, I want a update timetable python code. It's one of the element in admin menu which is to update school timetable. Hope it's clear

Answer (score 0):

Slight update to how you're storing your timetable

```py
timetable = {}
timetable.update({"Monday": ["English","Maths","Biology","Moral"]}]

timetable.get("Monday")
```

Using a dictionary instead of a list allows you to get a day, change the array then update it once you're done i.e.

```py
day = timetable.get("Monday")
day.append("Physics")
timetable.update({"Monday": day})
```